# Relation between abelian and free abelian group

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand the basic theory of free abelian groups and let me ask you the following question. This is the excerpt of the book which I'm reading.

> **Lemma (Universal property of free abelian group):** Let $X$- theset of generators of abelian group $F$, $|X|=n$. Then the following
>   statements are equivalent:
>
> (i) $F=F^{ab}_n$ - free abelian groups and $X$- the set of its
>   generators.
>
> (ii) Any mapping $\varphi:X\to A$ where $A$ - abelian group
>   induces the homomorphism $\tilde{\varphi}:F\to A$.
>
> **Corollary:** Any abelian group with $n$ generators is homomorphic image of some free abelian group $F^{ab}_n$.
>
> **Proof:** Follows immediately from univeral property.

However, for me is not clear how it follows from lemma. But I have done in the following way: suppose that $(A,+)$ is abelian group with generators $\{a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n\}$.  Let $F^{ab}_n$ be some free abelian group with generators $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Consider the mapping $\varphi:X\to A$ by $\varphi: x_i\mapsto a_i$ then we can consider the homomorphism $\tilde \varphi: F^{ab}_n\to A$ defined via $$\tilde \varphi:\sum k_ix_i \mapsto \sum k_ia_i.$$

Then easy to see that $\tilde \varphi(F^{ab}_n)=A$.

Is my proof looks correct?

But I was not able to derive it immediately from Universal property.

Would be very grateful for help!

Comment: The condition (ii) seems to be completely out of way. The usual (for me) universal property (ii) states that **any** map $\;\phi: X\to A\;$ , with $\;A\;$ any abelian group, can be **uniquely** extended to a homomorphism of abelian groups $\;\overline\phi: F_n^{ab}\to A\;$ ...Nothing about bijection.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Is my proof looks correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Extremely easy...and useful. Delete that "bijective" there. Completely nonsense.

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks a lot! Firstly I thought that without bijection the induced homomorphism will not be surjective.

Comment: If you leave the word "bijective, it'd mean $\;|A|=n\;$ , which of course not necessarily is true. It'd be true if you'd ask that the map be from $\;X\;$ to a generating set with $\;n\;$ elements of $\;A\;$ ...! Observe you also teh very important property of **uniqueness** ...which, btw, you did not prove as you didn't mention it. Read about this universal property anywhere in the web...even in Wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sort of partially reproving the universal property for this case, which is not needed.

The universal property ought to be stated as

> For every function $\phi: X \to A$ where $A$ is an Abelian group, there is a unique homomorphism $f:F= F^{\textrm{ab}}_n \to A$ such that $f| X=\phi$.

Now, if $A$ is Abelian group with your $n$ generators, indeed define $\phi(x_i) =a_i$ when $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} = X$. Then by the universal property, a homomorphism $f: F \to A$ exists, extending $\phi$.
As $f[X]=\phi[X]$ is a set of generators for $A$, $f[F]=A$, as $f[F]$ is a subgroup containing the $a_i$, and the smallest subgroup containing the $a_i$ is $A$ (that is what it means to be a generating set). So surjectivity is almost automatic, and we're done proving the corollary.

Comment: Very nice and good answer! +1